# menor fecha en distintos campos tablas mysql

Tags: mysql

Estimados tengo la siguiente duda, tengo estos registros de ejemplo en una tabla mysql

```
| fecha_1     | fecha_2    | fecha_3     |dni  |
| *2020-01-01*| 2020-03-01 | 2020-05-01  | 11  | 
| 2020-02-01  | 2020-03-01 | *2019-01-01*| 22  |
| *2020-02-01*| 2020-04-01 | 2020-06-01  | 33  |
```

lo que necesito es comparar las 3 fechas y que me muestre la menor separadas por dni de las 3 ejemplo

```
| MENOR fecha | dni  |
| 2020-01-01  |  11  | 
| 2019-01-01  | 22   |
| 2020-02-01  | 33   |
```

estoy haciendo consultas en mysql y he intentado con MIN pero eso me entrega la fecha de la columna, no por filas. tampoco me ha funcionado el BEETWEEN porque son muchos rangos de fechas..

agradeciendo sus consultas
Saludos

Comment: Primero vas a tener que comparar a mano por filas... no hay una funcion para lo que vos queres...

Comment: Usa la función [`least()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least): `SELECT least(fecha_1, fecha_2, fecha_3) menor, dni`.

Comment: no conocía esa función, aprendí algo nuevo :D

Comment: @Sal añade tu comentario como respuesta, así quedará más visible y además te ganas unos bien merecidos votos positivos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que hice fue encontrar el menor de 2 valores y ese valor compararlo con el tercero, así para cada fila, encontrando así el menor valor de los 3:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE la_tabla(
    dni INT PRIMARY KEY,
    fecha_1 VARCHAR(10),
    fecha_2 VARCHAR(10),
    fecha_3 VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO la_tabla(fecha_1,fecha_2,fecha_3,dni)
VALUES ('2020-01-01', '2020-03-01', '2020-05-01', 11),
('2020-02-01'  , '2020-03-01' , '2019-01-01', 22)  ,
('2020-02-01', '2020-04-01' , '2020-06-01'  , 33);

//La query:
SELECT IF(fecha_1 < fecha_2, 
IF(fecha_1 < fecha_3, fecha_1, fecha_3), 
IF(fecha_2 < fecha_3, fecha_2, fecha_3)) la_fecha_menor, dni
FROM la_tabla;
```

Answer (score 2):

La función [`least()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) te devuelve el menor valor de una lista de -por lo menos 2- argumentos.

```
SELECT least(fecha_1, fecha_2, fecha_3) menor, dni
```